# Implementing Graham Scan to find the convex hull

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, math, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the [Graham Scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan#Pseudocode) in C++ but it doesn't work and I can't find why. Any lead would be appreciated. After some tries it seems that I always have `m_M = 2` and the 2 points are the highest-y points, if that help.

Cross product to know if it's a right turn or a left turn.

```
qreal Interpolation::ccw(QPointF pt1, QPointF pt2, QPointF pt3)
{
    return (pt2.x()-pt1.x())*(pt3.y()-pt1.y()) - (pt2.y()-pt1.y())*(pt3.x()-pt1.x());
}
```

Dot product divided by the norm to have the `cos` because sorting the angle is the same as sorting the `cos in [0, Pi]`.

```
qreal Interpolation::dp(QPointF pt1, QPointF pt2)
{
    return (pt2.x()-pt1.x())/qSqrt((pt2.x()-pt1.x())*(pt2.x()-pt1.x()) + (pt2.y()-pt1.y())*(pt2.y()-pt1.y()));
}
```

The main function:

```
void Interpolation::ConvexHull()
{
    QPointF points[m_N+1]; // My number of points
    QPointF pt_temp(m_pt[0]);
    qreal angle_temp(0);
    int k_temp(0);
```

Fill the array points with `points[1]` being the lower-y point:

```
    for (int i(1); i < m_N; ++i)
    {
        if (m_pt[i].y() < pt_temp.y())
        {
            points[i+1] = pt_temp;
            pt_temp = m_pt[i];
        }
        else
        {
            points[i+1] = m_pt[i];
        }
    }
    points[1] = pt_temp;
```

Sorting the points array by angle and doing `points[m_N] = points[0]`

```
    for (int i(2); i <= m_N; ++i)
    {
        pt_temp = points[i];
        angle_temp = dp(points[1], pt_temp);
        k_temp = i;
        for (int j(1); j <= m_N-i; ++j)
        {
            if (dp(points[1], points[i+j]) < angle_temp)
            {
                pt_temp = points[i+j];
                angle_temp = dp(points[1], points[i+j]);
                k_temp = i+j;
            }
        }
        points[k_temp] = points[i];
        points[i] = pt_temp;
    }
    points[0] = points[m_N];
```

Executing the Graham scan

```
    m_M = 1; // Number of points on the convex hull.

    for (int i(2); i <= m_N; ++i)
    {
        while (ccw(points[m_M-1], points[m_M], points[i]) <= 0)
        {
            if (m_M > 1)
            {
                m_M -= 1;
            }
            else if (i == m_N)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        m_M += 1;
        pt_temp = points[m_M];
        points[m_M] = points[i];
        points[i] = points[m_M];
    }
```

Saving the points to `m_convexHull` which should be the list of the points on the hull with `ConvexHull[m_M]=[ConvexHull[0]`

```
    for (int i(0); i < m_M; ++i)
    {
        m_convexHull.push_back(points[i+1]);
    }
    m_convexHull.push_back(points[1]);
}
```

Comment: Leo, please don't edit questions with a solution you found yourself.  If you ask a question and then later find the answer on your own, post your answer as an answer, and leave the original post unchanged.  After the time has elapsed, you can then accept your own answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling I followed your advice and replaced the edit with a correct answer.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Now if a future StackOverflow user searches for this same problem, it will be easier to parse the problem from the solution.  After a few minutes have passed, you can accept your answer.  I've upvoted both the Q and A. Enjoy the rep. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem. It lies with the sentence:

> Dot product divided by the norm to have the cos because sorting the angle is the same as sorting the cos in [0, Pi].

The lower the angle, the higher the cos, so I just had to change this line of code:

```
            if (dp(points[1], points[i+j]) < angle_temp)
```

to:

```
            if (dp(points[1], points[i+j]) > angle_temp)
```

and now it works perfectly!